# About $A_{n+1}=A_{n}+A_{n}^{2}$ and OEIS $A122888$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion, logistic-regression, oeis

[OEIS A122888](https://oeis.org/A122888) is:    $1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 6, 9, 10, 8, 4, 1, 1, 4, 12, 30, 64, 118, 188, 258, 302, 298, 244, 162, 84, 32, 8, 1, 1, 5, 20, 70, 220, 630, 1656,\dots$

I'm having trouble understanding the definition:

> $T^{n}_{k}$ is the number of strings of length $k-1$ on the alphabet $ (1,2,\dots,n) $ such that between every two occurrences of a letter i there is an occurrence of a letter strictly larger than i. For example, for $n = 3, k = 4$ we have the strings $121, 131, 232$ and the six permutations of $123$.

$T=\left[
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& \dots \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& \dots \\
 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& \dots \\
 1 & 3 & 6 & 9 & 10 & 8 & 4 & 1& \dots \\
 1 & 4 & 12 & 30 & 64 & 118 & 188 & 258& \dots \\
 1 & 5 & 20 & 70 & 220 & 630 & 1656 & 4014& \dots \\
 1 & 6 & 30 & 135 & 560 & 2170 & 7916 & 27326& \dots \\
 1 & 7 & 42 & 231 & 1190 & 5810 & 27076 & 121023& \dots \\
 1 & 8 & 56 & 364 & 2240 & 13188 & 74760 & 409836& \dots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots& \ddots \\
\end{array}
\right]$

In addition I wonder what is the meaning behind multiplying the columns of $A122888$ by $(1−x)^k$ . I understand that it gives us $A122890$ ($H$) and that in a certain sense it is more "predictable" but what is the reasoning behind the choice of $(1−x)^k$ ?

$H=\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\
 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\dots\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 & 14 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0&\dots \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 70 & 42 & 0 & 0 & 0&\dots \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 160 & 424 & 132 & 0 & 0&\dots \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 250 & 1978 & 2382 & 429 & 0&\dots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots& \vdots& \ddots \\
\end{array}
\right]$

Comment: You deleted your earlier question, although I can still see it. The only thing one gets is that there is a limit of  $\frac{\log A_n}{2^n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=3$ and $k=4$, the strings on the alphabet $(1,2,3)$ length $k-1=3$ are $27$:
$$111,112,113,121,122,\dots,331,332,333.$$
We consider the strings in the list such that:

0) the letters are all different: $123,132,213,231,312,321$

1) between every two occurrences of a letter $1$ there is an occurrence 
of a letter $2$ or $3$: $121,131$.

2) between every two occurrences of a letter $2$ there is an occurrence of a letter $3$: $232$.

Therefore $T^{3}_{4}=6+2+1=9$.

As regards your second question, if we multiply a g.f. $f(x)=\sum_j a_jx^j$ by $(1-x)^k$ we obtain a new g.f. $\sum_n b_nx^n$ where the sequence of coefficients $(b_n)_n$ is a sort of binomial transform of the sequence $(a_j)_j$:
$$b_n=\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{k}{j}(-1)^ja_{n-j}.$$

Comment: thanks for this clear answer, but this answers my first question but not the second on the nature of $ (1-x) ^ {k} $. I'm currently thinking about whether to separate the questions. however I'm trying to understand how these permutations of the alphabet are connected to this recursive series, that is the polynomial $ A_ {n} $ with $ A_ {0} = x $

Comment: @PatrickDanzi The multiplication by $(1-x)^k$ is a sort of binomial transform of the original sequence, but I don't know why they are considering such transform.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform